# Stop collecting Flow in ViewModel when app in background

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-architecture-components, kotlin-flow

Need to **collect flow** in `ViewModel` and after some data modification, the UI is updated using `_batteryProfileState`.

Inside **compose** I'm **collecting states** like this

```kotlin
val batteryProfile by viewModel.batteryProfileState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
 batteryProfile.voltage
```

In `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
private val _batteryProfileState = MutableStateFlow(BatteryProfileState())
val batteryProfileState = _batteryProfileState.asStateFlow()

private fun getBatteryProfileData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {

          // FIXME In viewModel we should not collect it like this
         _batteryProfile(Unit).collect { result ->

               _batteryProfileState.update { state ->
                   when(result) {
                       is Result.Success -> {
                           state.copy(
                               voltage = result.data.voltage?.toString()
                                ?.plus(result.data.voltageUnit
                         )
                     }
                      is Result.Error -> {
                           state.copy(
                              errorMessage = _context.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong)
                         )
                     }
                }
             }
        }
     }
}
```

The problem is when I put my app in the background the `_batteryProfile(Unit).collect` does not stop collecting while in UI `batteryProfile.voltage` stop updating UI which is correct behavior as I have used `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` for UI.
But I have no idea how to achieve the same behavior for `ViewModel`.

Comment: You can't call this method twice - that'll cause you to be collecting twice (and if you call it three times, you'll be collecting three times). And if you're already collecting, what exactly is a 'refresh' going to do anyways? It doesn't change the thing you're already collecting from. Please explain how you think this is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right @ianhanniballake I can not refresh it. I do not know what I thought while writing this method.
Thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ViewModel` I have used `stateIn` operator and access data like below everything working fine now:

```
 val batteryProfileState = _batteryProfile(Unit).map { result ->
        when(result) {
            is Result.Success -> {
                BatteryProfileState(
                    voltage = result.data.voltage?.toString()
                        ?.plus(result.data.voltageUnit.unit)
                        ?: _context.getString(R.string.msg_unknown),
                )
            }
            is Result.Error -> {
                BatteryProfileState(
                    errorMessage = _context.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong)
                )
            }
        }
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, WhileViewSubscribed, BatteryProfileState())
```

**collecting data in composing will be the same**
Explanation: `WhileViewSubscribed` Stops updating data while the app is in the background for more than 5 seconds.

```
val WhileViewSubscribed = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define getBatteryProfileData() as suspend fun:

```
suspend fun getBatteryProfileData() {
       

            // FIXME In viewModel we should not collect it like this
            _batteryProfile(Unit).collect { result ->

                _batteryProfileState.update { state ->
                    when(result) {
                        is Result.Success -> {
                            state.copy(
                                voltage = result.data.voltage?.toString()
                                    ?.plus(result.data.voltageUnit
                            )
                        }
                        is Result.Error -> {
                            state.copy(
                                errorMessage = _context.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
```

And than in your composable define scope:

```
scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            scope.launch {
               yourviewmodel.getBatteryProfileData()
            }
```

And I think you can move suspend fun getBatteryProfileData() out of ViewModel class...

Comment: But why i will make this function public while I am exposing state from viewmodel for that.

Comment: Yes - you are getting the state from viewmodel. And you are updating the state by using viewmodel scope, but to be able to update the state correctly (in the way you want) you have to call the getBatteryProfileData in the composable scope. Instead of calling getBatteryProfileData in you viewmodel you have to call it from Composable.